# Cleanest way to remove common list elements across multiple lists in python

Tags: python, list, set

I have n lists of numbers. I want to make sure that each list contains unique elements to that particular list. I.e. There are no "shared" duplicates across any of the rest.
This is really easy to do with two lists, but a little trickier with n lists.

```
e.g.   
mylist = [
[1, 2, 3, 4],
[2, 5, 6, 7],
[4, 2, 8, 9]
]
```

becomes:

```
mylist = [
[1, 3],
[5, 6, 7],
[8, 9]
]
```

Comment: Why is 2 not in any of the three lists, whereas 4 is still present in the first list?

Comment: Do you care if order is preserved?

Comment: Use a bag (`default_dict`) to build a "seen" list. Replace each list of `mylist` (I'll call it `sublist`) with a generator that looks for a matching `seen`: if found, don't include it in the final `sublist`. If not found, add it to the bag.

Comment: what is your expected output for `mylist = [[1, 2, 2], [3]]` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain

mylist = [
    [1,2,3,4],
    [2,5,6,7,7],
    [4,2,8,9]
]

counts = Counter(chain(*map(set,mylist)))

[[i for i in sublist if counts[i]==1] for sublist in mylist]
#[[1, 3], [5, 6, 7, 7], [8, 9]]
```

Comment: This is really nice, but I would prefer not to have to import Counter and chain I guess as this might slightly reduce the running time (?).

Comment: !!! I was looking for a way to do `chain(*mylist)` in my answer in an elegant way. Very nice. Oops, and I don't even need `.get()` like in my answer because of course it'll always be defined. I'm deleting my answer because yours is almost exactly the same but strictly better.

Comment: @MatthewRNYC: you should not be afraid of using basic collections like this answer suggests. Additionally I can see no reason that `chain` and the `Counter` constructor would not both be `O(N)`.

Comment: It does not preserve duplicates in one list though.

Comment: this is a good solution, and there is nothing wrong with using libraries such as collections or itertools when appropriate

Comment: @FelixKling: I just realized this and fixed dugres's answer. The trick is to count numbers at most once from each list (`map(set,mylist)` rather than `mylist`).

Answer (score 2):

This does it in linear time, 2 passes. I'm assuming you want to preserve duplicates within a list; if not, this can be simplified a bit:

```
>>> import collections, itertools
>>> counts = collections.defaultdict(int)
>>> for i in itertools.chain.from_iterable(set(l) for l in mylist):
...     counts[i] += 1
... 
>>> for l in mylist:
...     l[:] = (i for i in l if counts[i] == 1)
... 
>>> mylist
[[1, 3], [5, 6, 7], [8, 9]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't care about order, you can easily remove duplicates using set subtraction and converting back to list.  Here it is in a monster one-liner:

```
>>> mylist = [
... [1, 2, 3, 4],
... [2, 5, 6, 7],
... [4, 2, 8, 9]
... ]
>>> mynewlist = [list(set(thislist) - set(element for sublist in mylist for element in sublist if sublist is not thislist)) for thislist in mylist]
>>> mynewlist
[[1, 3], [5, 6, 7], [8, 9]]
```

***Note:*** This is not very efficient because duplicates are recomputed for each row.  Whether this is a problem or not depends on your data size.

Comment: Looks like an expensive operation though. If you have `n` lists with `m` elements each you have something like `O(n * n-1 * m)` (that's only for iterating over each element of each sublist). Or am I wrong?

Comment: Unfortunately I have to -1: this recalculates all duplicates for each list, resulting in roughly `O(N^(3/2))` work assuming the number of sublists is like `sqrt(N)`. Nor does it preserve the order of a list (though if the lists were sorted, you could re-sort them, at a cost of a multiplicative `O(log(sublistN))` factor extra). I would personally go with the `Counter` solution which I believe is `O(N)`.

Comment: That is true. I guess I should choose the faster one :/

Comment: True, it is not efficient - I will add a disclaimer to the answer.   But is that a problem?  I am always in habit to ask "Does it need to be efficient?" before I ask "How can I make this more efficient?"

Comment: @MatthewRNYC the 'faster' one depends on your data size.  for example, with the data in your question, this list comprehension is actually about twice as fast as the `Counter` solution.

Comment: @ninjagecko 1. I asked if order is to preserved _before_ posting this answer, the response from op was order did not matter here  2. Optimising code before you can see a bottleneck in the workflow is a bad habit.  O(N^2) or worse can be quite fine when N will not be very large, so it depends on the use case  3. I don't think you should feel that any working solution deserves a downvote - the FAQ here says to use your downvotes for "sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect".  By all means reserve your upvote for those concerns, but why -1?

Comment: @wim: Yes, premature optimization is bad. The hover says "this answer is not useful" and I didn't find it useful since: 1) it was 157-character one-liner (not that one-liners are bad, but it was not readable in less than thirty seconds; and one-liners should be indented imho), 2) there was a straightforward more-elegant `O(N)` solution as opposed to an `O(N^2)` solution, 3) I saw an unnecessary `enumerate` which was sloppy. I still believe #2 is reasonable for a downvote, but I now find the `is not` part useful, the enumerate is gone, and you address performance, so I've removed my downvote.

Comment: #2 is a reason to upvote that straightforward and elegant solution.  it is not really a reason to put -1 onto other solutions, this is stifling creativity on stackoverflow.  Of course I could make it into an < 80 character line like this `l=[list(set(t) - set(x for s in m for x in s if s is not t)) for t in m]` but it's not maybe not as self-documenting for understanding how the comprehension works  :)  not sure what you mean by indenting one-liners.

Answer (score 0):

set() is the right approach.
although you don't have to use a list comprehension.

Without additional imports:

```
mylist = [
[1, 2, 3, 4],
[2, 5, 6, 7],
[4, 2, 8, 9]
]
>>> result_list = []
>>> for test_list in mylist:
...     result_set = set(test_list)
...     for compare_list in mylist:
...         if test_list != compare_list:
...             result_set = result_set - set(compare_list)
...     result_list.append(result_set)
...
>>> result_list
[set([1, 3]), set([5, 6, 7]), set([8, 9])]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution, using [`Counter`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to build a set of all the common numbers, and then it just does a set difference:

```
from collections import Counter

def disjoin(lsts):
    c = Counter(num for lst in lsts for num in lst)
    common = set(x for x,v in c.items() if v > 1)
    result = []
    for lst in lsts:
        result.append(set(lst) - common)
    return result
```

Example:

```
>>> remove_common(mylist)
[set([1, 3]), set([5, 6, 7]), set([8, 9])]
```